# Intrinsic and extrinsic distance on minimal submanifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $\Sigma\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a $k$-dimensional complete minimal submanifold. Let $d(x,y)$ be the intrinsic distance between $x,y\in \Sigma$ and $|x-y|$ be the Euclidean distance. Let $y\in\Sigma$ be fixed. Do we have
$$|x-y|\le C\Longrightarrow \text{ there is }R>0 \text{ such that }d(x,y)\le R?$$

This is not true for general submanifolds in $\mathbb R^n$ since one can have the topologist sine curve.

Comment: I guess this is not true, and the complete embedded minimal surface in a ball should be a counterexample

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments. What if we require $\Sigma$ to be area minimizing?

Comment: I think you meant to say that $R$ depends only on $C$ (and maybe on $y$). Otherwise, the answer is obviously positive (provided that $\Sigma$ is connected).